# How can i connect to a meteor.js mongodb instance from a diffrent node.js proccess

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

How can i connect to the meteor.js mongodb instance from a different node.js process.
i have noticed that the meteor.js mongodb is different then then my local mongod instance
and that i cant locate the collections i have on my meteor app in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your meteor process is running, type this command into your console:

```
$ ps aux | grep mongod
```

One of those lines represents the mongod instance started by meteor. Take note of the `--port` argument. Let's assume that it's 3001. From node you can then connect to localhost on port 3001 and the database name should be `meteor`.

For example, if you were using the [mongodb native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) you could do something like:

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor', function(err, db) {
  ...
});
```

If you wish to connect to the mongo shell you could do:

```
$ mongo --port 3001 meteor
```

From the root directory of your meteor application you can also connect with:

```
$ meteor mongo
```

Comment: Thank you David. you provided a full answer to my problem. it's working.